# Error (10818): Can't infer register because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge, how to fix it?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I have this code for a ram in VHDL and I get the following error while synthesis:

Error (10818): Can't infer register for "data_table[19][13]" at RAM.vhd(50) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

any help would be appreciated!

here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity RAM is
    port (
    clk, wr_en : in std_logic;
        address: in std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);
        data_in : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    data_out: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)
  );
end entity RAM;

architecture RAM_Arch of RAM is
    type Memory is array (0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
  signal data_table : Memory := (others => (others => '0'));

begin
    process (clk)
        variable init : boolean := true;

    begin
        if init = true then
            -- some initiation
            data_table(0) <= "0001010000011010";
            data_table(1) <= "0011110000001000";
            data_table(2) <= "0011110000010000";
            data_table(3) <= "0011110000100000";
            data_table(4) <= "0011110000000001";
            data_table(10) <= "0001010000011100";
      data_table(11) <= "0100000000000001";
      data_table(12) <= "0011110000000001";
      data_table(13) <= "0011110000000010";
      data_table(14) <= "0011110000000100";
      data_table(15) <= "0011110000001000";
      data_table(16) <= "0011110000010000";
      data_table(17) <= "0011110000100000";
      -- data_table(18) <= "0011110001000000";
      data_table(19) <= "1011110000010000";
      -- data_table(19) <= "1011110000000001";
      -- data_table(20) <= "1011110000000010";
      -- data_table(21) <= "1011110000000100";
      -- data_table(22) <= "1011110000001000";
      -- data_table(24) <= "1011110000100000";
      -- data_table(25) <= "1011110001000000";
      -- data_table(26) <= "1011110010000000";
            init := false;
        end if;

        if  clk'event and clk = '1' then
            if wr_en = '1' then -- Writing :)
               data_table(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= data_in;
      end if;
        end if;
    end process;

  data_out <= data_table(to_integer(unsigned(address)));

end architecture RAM_Arch;
```

Comment: So what would happen if you eliminated the first `end if;` and made the second `if` and `elsif` instead? Your code violates IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) [6.1.3.1 Edge-senstive storage from a process with sensitivity list and one clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeUcL.jpg) rule b)., The async assignment is in an independent if statement from the sync assignment on the clock edge which can override the async assignment. The RTL Synthesis standard was withdrawn from lack of vendor participation and the vendor doesn't document the rules elsewhere other than 'correct' examples.

Comment: Remove the init, make it an initialisation function instead.

Comment: Intel® Quartus® Prime Pro Edition User Guide: Design Recommendations[1.4.1.11. Specifying Initial Memory Contents at Power-Up](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/740111?fileName=ug-683082-740111.pdf). There are also Xilinx device families that support reset to initial value. Their patent implementing doing so has recently expired and the idea might spread to other device vendors.

Answer (score 0):

If your code must be synthesized never put non-synchronous assignments in a synchronous process. Try:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ram is
  port (
    clk, wr_en: in std_logic;
    address:    in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    data_in :   in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    data_out:  out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
  );
end entity ram;

architecture ram_arch of ram is

  type memory is array (0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
  signal data_table: memory := (
     0 => "0001010000011010",
     1 => "0011110000001000",
     2 => "0011110000010000",
     3 => "0011110000100000",
     4 => "0011110000000001",
    10 => "0001010000011100",
    11 => "0100000000000001",
    12 => "0011110000000001",
    13 => "0011110000000010",
    14 => "0011110000000100",
    15 => "0011110000001000",
    16 => "0011110000010000",
    17 => "0011110000100000",
    -- 18 => "0011110001000000",
    19 => "1011110000010000",
    -- 19 => "1011110000000001",
    -- 20 => "1011110000000010",
    -- 21 => "1011110000000100",
    -- 22 => "1011110000001000",
    -- 24 => "1011110000100000",
    -- 25 => "1011110001000000",
    -- 26 => "1011110010000000",
    others => (others => '0'));

begin

  process (clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if wr_en = '1' then -- writing :)
        data_table(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= data_in;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  data_out <= data_table(to_integer(unsigned(address)));

end architecture ram_arch;
```

Note: you should probably not use `std_logic`. If you do not know the difference with `std_ulogic` prefer the latter. Same with `std_logic_vector`: prefer `std_ulogic_vector`.